# Fingerprint has already been taken - GIT

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I am trying to generate a new pair of SSH keys, but upon generating (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com" -b 4096`), the existing key in the indicated folder does not get updated despite the status **Your identification has been saved in ir_rsa2** and **Your public key has been saved in ir_rsa2.pub** and a freshly generated key fingerprint in console, so when adding the key to git repository I'm getting error *'Fingerprint has already been taken'*. What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Fingerprint has already been taken.
> ```

That means you are copying a public key you already registered before.

You should see new files in `~/.ssh`

In your case, you should copy the content of `~/.ssh/ir_rsa2.pub` to your Git server web GUI.

If you do not see those files, try again this time by specifying the file directly:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com" -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/ir_rsa2
```